# Ask for user input and insert in DB in python with sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

At the moment I try to ask the user for input in Python, to enter some information (here: expenseID, expense, categoryID, date). But I do not know were to start. No input validation is necessary at this step.

I managed to access my database and INSERT something manually. I tried several ways of the python `input` function but cannot use it as a placeholder in the SQL string.

```py
import sqlite3 

with sqlite3.connect('Expenses.sqlite') as conn:
    # INSERT MANUALLY
    script = "INSERT INTO Expense (ExpenseId, Amount, CategoryId, Date) VALUES ('103', '43625.5', '5', '2019-01-20');"
    conn.execute(script) # execute the script
    conn.commit()  # commit changes to the file
    # INSERT USER INPUT ???
    pass
```

This is my idea:

```
with sqlite3.connect('Expenses.sqlite') as conn:

    amount = input("What is the amount?")
    script = "SELECT * FROM Category;"
    conn.execute(script)
    print(script)
    category = input("What is the category?")
    exp_ID = "SELECT LAST ExpenseId FROM Expense);"
    date = datetime.date.today()
    script = "INSERT INTO Expense (ExpenseId, Amount, CategoryId, Date) VALUES (exp_ID, amount, category, date);"
    conn.execute(script)
    conn.commit()
    pass
```

Finally I want to achieve that the user is asked for amount of expense, and afterwards for expense category. ExpenseID and date should be added automatically. Date format is year-month-day. Thank you very much for advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function to retrieve the user input

```
user_input = input("Expense Amount: ")
```

Then use [placeholders](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) with sqlite3

```
sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE (COLUMN) VALUES (?)"
conn.execute(sql, (user_input,))
```

**in response to your edit

You need to add placeholders instead of the variable names.

Something like this:

```
script = "INSERT INTO Expense (ExpenseId, Amount, CategoryId, Date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);"
conn.execute(script, (exp_ID,amount,category,date))
```

Comment: This says absolutely nothing about how to insert data into an SQLite DB

Comment: Yes, my mistake I did not fully read the question. Edited my answer

Comment: I tried input outside of sql-connection but did not manage to include it in script by any placeholder. That's my first problem.

Comment: So, it looks like a great idea, but I get IntegrityError with this approach. Regards

Comment: IntegrityError is a sqlite exception. Check your column definitions.